# sort and print a specific field of a multy-field file in a bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

my file has the form

> field1|fild2|fild3|field4

```
sort pt '|' -k2 -i $1 && cut -d '|' -f2 $2
```

this only sorts a file and print it, after that just prints the column 2
i want make those steps in once: print the sorted column 2 only. Is this possible with the sort command?

Comment: `sort` just sorts it doesn't select fields. If you wanted `cut` there to operate on the sorted output then you wanted `sort ... | cut ...` to send/pipe the output from `sort` into `cut`. With `sort ... && cut ...` you have two independent commands (which is why you need to give `cut` a filename to operate on in `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

cut the selected field first and sort

```
$ cut -d'|' -f2 file | sort
```